# Can anyone give me example on receiveAndReply using Springe AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp

I am trying ti use Spring AMQP 1.3, so can anyone give me request reply example using receiveAndReply API in Springe AMQP.

Answer (score 0):

[See the project documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e526).